# MSPage addLayer undefined

Tags: sketchapp

I'm writing a demo that working with Layer and Page.

My code looks like:

```
layer = [MSLayer new]
[[doc currentPage] addLayer:layer] //<= addLayer is undefined
```

I saw in the [Sketch plugin API for MSPage](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/developer/03-reference/MSPage.html) has the `addLayer` function.

I'm running Sketch 3.2.2

Answer (score 2):

I inspected the MSLayerGroup class and found that addLayer is replaced by addLayers, which takes an array of MSLayer.

Now I use the following code to add layer into group:

```
// In Sketch 3.3.2 (or earlier), addLayer is replaced by addLayers.
var addLayerToGroup = function(group, layer) {
  if (group.addLayer == undefined) {
    [group addLayers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:layer]];
  } else {
    [group addLayer:layer];
  }
}
```